# Optimal solution for linear program given that both primal slack forms are feasible

Tags: linear-programming

I'm given a linear program `P` in a standard form.

I need to prove that if both the primal slack form of `P` and primal slack form of the dual problem are feasible, then the optimal solution for `P` is `0`.

I've trie to work with [Weak Duality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_duality#Weak_duality_theorem), but can't get the math together.

Any help would be appericiated.

Comment: Can specify what you mean by 'slack from'? I was studying Linear Optimization at the university and to be honest it's the first time I hear about slack form.

Comment: @serge_k According to Wikipedia it may be better known as `Augmented_form`
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Augmented_form_.28slack_form.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Duality Theorem if a primal problem admits an optimal solution (x*1,….x*n) then the dual problem admits an optimal solution (y*1, ….y*m) such that all feasible solutions of the program in primal form are bounded from above by that of the dual program, and we can say the opposite holds true as well, that feasible solutions of the dual are bounded from below by those of the primal, meaning that if the two have the same solution then it is the optimal solution of the linear program.

Put simply, the optimal solution is bound from below by feasible solutions of the primal program and from above by feasible solutions of the dual program.

In this case it is given that both primal and dual basic slack forms of the program are feasible, meaning that the basic solution to the slack form is a feasible solution. The basic slack form’s feasible solution is 0 (remember we set all non-basic variables to zero when solving for basic solution). Thus we know that for both the dual and primal program 0 is a feasible solution and so from the duality we know that 0 is the optimal solution of the linear program.

We can prove this by negation. Take some non-zero number k and some non-zero number j such that k is a feasible solution for the linear program’s primal form and j is a feasible solution for the linear program’s dual form. The optimal solution of the linear program occurs when j=k. Let us show that this cannot happen for any number other than 0.

For any feasible solution k of the primal program we know that it is bound from above by all feasible solutions of the dual program. Since we know that one such solution is 0, since the basic slack form of the dual program is feasible, then we know that k must be a non-positive number. 
For any feasible solution j of the dual program we know that it is bound from below by all feasible solutions of the primal program. Since we know that one such solution is 0, since the basic slack form of the primal program is feasible, then we know that j must be a non-negative number.

Having shown that any feasible solution of the dual, j,  is non-negative, and any feasible solution of the primal, k,  is non-positive, we see that the j=k for a non zero number is a contradiction.
The only number that can possibly obtain j=k is 0, and thus is the optimal solution.